# Make QLineEdit detect Tab Key Press event?

Tags: qt

I couldn't find anything in the docs. I found one solution that uses PyQt or something, but I'd rather not have to use that. Also, it would be pretty nice if there was a signal for it, but it doesn't look like there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.When you install an event filter as Sam suggested (`m_lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);`) you need to handle `QEvent::KeyPress` and check the key to be equal `Qt::Key_Tab`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (obj == m_lineEdit) {
     if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
         QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
         if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
         {
             //do what you need;
             return true;
         }             
  }
     // pass the event on to the parent class
     return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

2.Another way to do that is to create a new class inherited from QLineEdit and reimplement `keyPressEvent`:

```
void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
  if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
  {
     emit tabPressed();
     return;
  }
  QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `QObject::installEventFilter(QObject*)` to intercept the key press event. There's an example here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter .